# How can I get OBS Studio with the Browser Source Plugin on Debian?

Tags: plugin, obs-studio

According to the repository for the Browser Plugin for Linux,

> Good news! Starting with version 25, OBS Studio ships with browser source that work on Linux. I recommend you to use that and report any issues at obs-browser repo and/or official discord community.

I'm using Debian Testing which Ships OBS Studio 26. However, it lacks Browser Plugin.

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, it seems you’ll need to build OBS Studio yourself to get the browser plugin. [The plugin has been requested](https://bugs.debian.org/956086), but [it needs the Chromium Embedded Framework to be packaged first](https://bugs.debian.org/915400).

Alternatively, you could try one of the Ubuntu packages from [the OBS Studio PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eobsproject/+archive/ubuntu/obs-studio), with the usual caveat that Ubuntu isn’t Debian.